# Equivalent of Beautiful Soup's renderContents() method in lxml?

Tags: python, xml, rendering, beautifulsoup, lxml

Is there an equivalent of Beautiful Soup's `tag.renderContents()` method in lxml?

I've tried using `element.text`, but that doesn't render child tags, as well as `''.join(etree.tostring(child) for child in element)`, but that doesn't render child text. The closest I've been able to find is `etree.tostring(element)`, but that renders the opening and closing tags of `element`, which I do not want.

Is there another method I'm overlooking (or an alternative approach to accomplish this)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're most of the way there with your original idea. `element.text` gives you the first text child of the element, and your list comprehension gives you everything else. If you concatenate the two strings together, you get what you're looking for:

```
>>> xmlstr = "<sec>header <p>para 0</p> text <p>para 1</p> footer</sec>"
>>> element = etree.fromstring(xmlstr)
>>>
>>> element.text + "".join(map (etree.tostring, element))
'header <p>para 0</p> text <p>para 1</p> footer'
>>>
```

Ari.

Answer (score 0):

One hackish solution:

```
from lxml import etree
def render_contents(element):
    """
    Surely there is a safe lxml built-in for this...
    """
    tagname = element.tag
    return re.sub('</%s>\s*$' % tagname, '',
                  re.sub(r'^<%s(\s+\w+=".*?")*?>' % tagname,
                         '', etree.tostring(element))).strip()
```

### Edit

Really, there's no better method than this?